# How can I test the 'error' and 'close' events of a node server request stream?

Tags: node.js, http, server

We have a production issue on our server, where the [request stream for an incoming HTTP request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) doesn't get an `end` event; presumably there is a `error` or `close` event instead through some fault in the request/connection.

My questions are:

1. What would cause the `error` or `close` events in an HTTP request?
2. How can I write an integration test (or failing that a unit test) to test these conditions?

Answer (score 1):

I found that I can simulate a prematurely closed request by exiting the process without calling `res.end()`, this triggers the `close` event on the server (the `end` event is never called):

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  path: '/',
  method: 'POST',
  port: 3000
};
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {});

req.write('123');

setTimeout(function() {
  process.exit();
}, 100);
```

I still don't know how to trigger an `error` event.

Answer (score 0):

The `end` event (documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end)) will only be emitted when the request object (which happens to also be a `ReadableStream` instance) is drained.

So you need to consume all the data (even if you're not interested in it) before it will trigger:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  req.on('close', function() {
    console.log('close');
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('error', e);
  }).on('end', function() {
    console.log('end');
    res.end('hello world');
  }).on('data', function() { // <- drain the stream
    // do nothing...
  });
}).listen(3012);
```

The `close` event is emitted when the connection from the client to the server is closed (usually when the client closes the connection before the response is sent), and the `error` event is emitted when "errors" occur (presumably when something "under the hood" fails).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already reading all the data. I want to know more specifically about what happens 'under the hood' in these fail states.

Comment: @peterjwest catch the event and log it?